# Firefox Addon Scripting Trusted Page Content

Tags: javascript, firefox, content-script

So I'm trying to use a chrome:// URI in my add-on and I want to use a page-worker on it using the scripting trusted content method, however it seems to not work when I hard code the URI in, the `chrome://<package name>/<part>/<file>`; however, it works when I use the self.data.url('filename'). I want to use the chrome:// URI is because I use a GUID instead of the email style as the add-on's ID and also I don't want to use the resource:// URI.

Content Script

```
addon.port.emit('hi');
```

HTML

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Gaia Utils Settings</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="chrome://gaiascripts/content/dropdown.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="chrome://gaiascripts/content/settings.dev.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="chrome://gaiascripts/content/test.dev.js"></script>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <link href="css/settings.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <link href="css/poststyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <nav id="navbar_header" class="navbar navbar-blue navbar-static-top"></nav>
      <div id="content_wrapper" class="container">
         <div id="content_padding" class="container"></div>
      </div>
      <footer class="footer"></footer>
   </body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
var PageWorker = require("sdk/page-worker");
PageWorker.Page({
   contentURL: "chrome://gaiautils/content/settings.dev.html",
   onMessage: function(message) {
      console.log(message);
   }
});
```

I know I can use a page-mod and attach the scripts to it with that, but I'd rather call the scripts from within the file and be able to communicate with the main add-on code. So is there a way so that I can have my cake and eat it too - using the hard coded chrome:// URI in conjunction with calling the scripts from within the HTML file while being able to have those scripts communicate back to the main.js file?

Comment: **Never** load remote scripts in your add-on code!

Comment: As for the rest of the question: What is your problem exactly? What doesn't work? What's the error when you try?

Comment: The question is, since I'm using the chrome:// URI how can I have it so that I can use the addon.port.emit() in the content scripts that are called directly in the HTML file so that I don't have to use the self.data.url('htmlFile'), because I don't want to use the resource://pageckage-GUID-at-jetpack/path/to/file

Like I said, I know I can use page-mods, but that means I'm not calling the script files within the HTML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I have it so that I can use the addon.port.emit() in the content scripts that are called directly in the HTML file so that I don't have to use the self.data.url('htmlFile'), because I don't want to use the resource://pageckage-GUID-at-jetpack/path/to/file

The SDK only considers pages "trusted" if the URL you're loading is part of the add-on assets (`data/`). `chrome://` URIs are not. Hence you'll need to use regular content scripts via the `contentScriptFile: [...]` option in your PageWorker definition.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

Don't ever load remote scripts for security reasons (and performance reasons to a far lesser extent)! Ship a local copy of jQuery if you want to use it.

Comment: Well that kind of sucks, but it makes sense. Thanks! 
So then if I'm going to use the contentScriptFile, what's the difference between that and a page-mod when it comes to injecting content scripts to the page, is there a difference? I know with page-mods you can add a stylesheet as well.

Thanks for the local jQ file advice.